# Remove extra dot in a String by grep/awk/cut

Tags: awk, grep, cut, tail

I have the following text in a file,  for example, output.txt

```
[test.tracking_utils] INFO: Tracking subtool usage: main_test
[TEST & SPEC] INFO: Uploaded file test.zip with bucket URI test/20210804144418.zip.
```

How to use grep o something similar to get the value as `test/20210804144418.zip`?

I tried

```
tail output.txt | grep ". test/" | awk {print $NF}
tail output.txt | grep -m1 .test/ | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

it returns `test/20210804144418.zip.` with extra `.` do you know how to remove the extra `.` at the end? any suggestion?

Comment: What does the scrip that is producing `output.txt` look like? Is it a script you can change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```sh
grep -oE -m1 'test/[^[:blank:]]+\.[^.]+' file

test/20210804144418.zip
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `test/`: Match `test/`
- `[^[:blank:]]+`: Match 1+ of non-whitespace characters
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `[^.]+`: Match 1+ of any non-dot characters

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a trailing `.` by piping through

```
sed 's/\.$//'
```

But this may not be necessary in this case. With GNU `grep` or `pcregrep` you can extract just the path directly:

```
grep -Po 'with bucket URI \K.*(?=.)'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, you could try following once.

```
awk '/test\//{sub(/\.$/,"");print $(NF);exit}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` here.

```
awk 'match($0,/URI test\/[0-9]+\.zip/){print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4);exit}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- start of desired output/string doesn't necessarily start with `test`
- all lines with the desired string contain `with bucket URI`
- string of interest will always be the last field (in a space-delimited) line
- there may be more than one line of interest

Sample input:

```
$ cat output.txt
[test.tracking_utils] INFO: Tracking subtool usage: main_test
[TEST & SPEC] INFO: Uploaded file test.zip with bucket URI test/20210804144418.zip.
[test.tracking_utils] INFO: Tracking subtool usage: main_test
[TEST & SPEC] INFO: Uploaded file test.zip with bucket URI other/101423412.pre.zip.
```

A couple `awk` ideas:

```
awk '/with bucket URI/{sub(/\.$/,"",$NF);print $NF}' output.txt
awk '/with bucket URI/{print substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1)}' output.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
test/20210804144418.zip
other/101423412.pre.zip
```